How to handle normalized attribute stripping away % characters when building LIKE query in arel?
Setup:
rails new testing --minimal
cd testing

bin/rails g model Property name handle --no-timestamps
bin/rails db:migrate
sed -i '2i \  normalizes :handle, with: ->(handle) { handle.to_s.underscore.parameterize(separator: "_") }' app/models/property.rb

# app/models/property.rb

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :handle, with: ->(handle) { handle.to_s.underscore.parameterize(separator: "_") }
end


handle normalization is expected when creating/updating a record and when searching:
Property.create(name: "My property", handle: "  My   property ")
#=> #<Property:0x00007f9b3a0e2e50 id: 1, name: "My property", handle: "my_property">
#                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^

Property.where(handle: "  myProperty  ").to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"properties\".* FROM \"properties\" WHERE \"properties\".\"handle\" = 'my_property'"
#                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^

But when building a LIKE query with arel the % characters are also stripped away, which should be part of the query:
Property.arel_table[:handle].matches("%prop%").to_sql
#=> "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE 'prop'"
#                                    ^^^^

Can I avoid doing where("handle LIKE ?") and always keep handle normalized?

This problem was raised in this Rails issue. Looks like there is no plan to fix this as it's not part of the public API.
You can get around the wildcard getting filtered with a quoted arel node (which doesn't get cast):
search_condition = Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new("%prop%")
Property.arel_table[:handle].matches(search_condition).to_sql
# => "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE '%prop%'"   

And if you want to apply the normalization before searching:
normalized_term = Property.normalize_value_for(:handle, "PROP EXAMPLE") # => "prop_example"
search_condition = Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new("%#{normalized_term}%")
Property.arel_table[:handle].matches(search_condition).to_sql
# => "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE '%prop_example%'"   


Arel::Nodes exposes a #build_quoted method which I find a little nicer e.g  Arel::Nodes.build_quoted("%#{normalized_term}%")

wish there were some kind of Arel::Nodes::Wildcarded or .matches(contains: "prop"). @coalest thank you, this will work just fine.

There is no way for matches to safely separate % from the attribute value, so normalizing ahead of time is a much simpler approach.
The arel way would look something like this:
module Arel
  module Nodes
    class Wildcard < Arel::Nodes::Node
      def initialize(expr, node)
        @node = node
        @expr = expr
      end
      def value_for_database
        @node.value_for_database
      end
      def contains?   = @expr == :contains
      def start_with? = @expr == :start_with
      def end_with?   = @expr == :end_with
    end
  end

  module Visitors
    class ToSql
      def visit_Arel_Nodes_Wildcard(o, collector)
        str = ""
        str << "%" if o.contains? || o.end_with?
        str << o.value_for_database
        str << "%" if o.contains? || o.start_with?
        collector << quote(str)
      end
    end
  end

  module Predications
    def like(expr, value, escape = nil, case_sensitive = false)
      Nodes::Matches.new self, Nodes::Wildcard.new(expr, quoted_node(value)), escape, case_sensitive
    end
  end
end

Property.arel_table[:handle].like(:contains, "  my prop ").to_sql
#=> "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE '%my_prop%'"

Property.arel_table[:handle].like(:start_with, "  myProp ").to_sql
#=> "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE 'my_prop%'"

Property.arel_table[:handle].like(:end_with, "%my!prop% ").to_sql
#=> "\"properties\".\"handle\" LIKE '%my_prop'"

